# Validate a String to Double with max digits

Tags: java, double

For example when I parse a string "12345678901234567890" to double using Double.parseDouble() it returns the value "12345678901234567000" since it can hold up to 17 digits.

I want to validate this scenario and the user should be allowed to pass only 17 digits. How do I do this?

Example : 
1.2345678901234567890 is invalid because it has more than 17 digits total
1.2345E+10 is valid

Comment: Be careful with this.  You _could_ use something like `if (myString.length() > 17)` but that's no guarantee that converting to a `double` won't do any rounding.

Comment: Doing that correctly via regular expressions will be **way** more complex than you imagine it. As a trivial example: "12345678901234567890" does not fit into a `Double`without any loss of precision, but "12345678901234567000" **does** fit in, even though its the same number of digits. So not only will you have to check the length of the string, but also how many of the digits are "relevant". And no, it won't always be "0 is ok, everything else isn't" because `double` care about what's representable in binary, the decimal representation doesn't intuitively map towards that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try `System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("12345678901234568000"));`?  The result may not be what you expect.  In general, you can only trust the first 15 significant figures of a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like this which can count the digits using split function

```
String input="12345678901234567E100";
    String inputWithoutSign;
    int lengthFullNumber;
    int lengthFraction;
    double v = Double.parseDouble(input);
    if(input.startsWith("+") || input.startsWith("-")){
        inputWithoutSign = input.split("[-+]",2)[1];
    }
    else inputWithoutSign = input;

    String num = inputWithoutSign.split("[eE]", 2)[0];

    if(num.indexOf('.') == -1){
        lengthFullNumber = num.length();
        lengthFraction = 0;
    }else{
        String[] splitNum = num.split("\\.", 2);

        lengthFullNumber = splitNum[0].length();

        lengthFraction = splitNum[1].length();
    }

    System.out.println("length:"+(lengthFullNumber+lengthFraction));
```

Comment: Why do want to do this?  Wouldn't it be easier to use Double.parseDouble() and catch the exception for invalid input?

Comment: I do not want to lose any digits from the user's input. In the example "12345678901234567890", parseDouble gives me "12345678901234567000".

Answer (score 0):

Presuming I understand your goal of limiting the number of digits, this may help solve the problem.

Test cases

```java
      String[] vals = {
            "12345678901234567890", "123456789091919191919",
            "182828282.18282828", "182828282.182828282", "191929e10",
            "192929.22929e10"
      };
```

Try and parse them

```java
      for (String v : vals) {
         // remove possible decimal point and signs
         String test = v.replaceAll("[.+-]", "");
         // remove any exponents at end of string
         test = test.replace("\\D+.*", "");
         if (test.length() > 17) {
            System.out.println(v + " has too many digits");
            continue;
         }
         double d = Double.parseDouble(v);
         System.out.println(v + " parses to " + d);
      }
```